# selecting duplicates by condition python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe which I would like to separate from each other with some conditions.

| Car | Year | Speed | Cond |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 2001 | 150 | X |
| BMW | 2000 | 150 |  |
| Audi | 1997 | 200 |  |
| Audi | 2000 | 200 |  |
| Audi | 2012 | 200 | X |
| Fiat | 2020 | 180 |  |
| Mazda | 2022 | 183 |  |

What i have to do is take duplicates to another dataframe and in my main dataframe leave only one line.

- Rows that are duplicates in the `Car` column I would like to separate into a separate dataframe, but I don't need the ones that have X in the `cond` column.
- In main dataframe I would like keep one row. I would like the left row to be the one that contains X in the `cond` column

I have code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = {'Car': {0: 'BMW', 1: 'BMW', 2: 'Audi', 3: 'Audi', 4: 'Audi', 5: 'Fiat', 6: 'Mazda'},
        'Year': {0: 2001, 1: 2000, 2: 1997, 3: 2000, 4: 2012, 5: 2020, 6: 2022},
        'Speed': {0: 150, 1: 150, 2: 200, 3: 200, 4: 200, 5: 180, 6: 183},
        'Cond': {0: 'X', 1: np.nan, 2: 'X', 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: np.nan}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cars)
df_duplicates = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['Car'], keep = False)].loc[df['Cond']!='X']
```

I don't know how i can leave the main dataframe with only one row which additionally contains `X` in `cond` column
Maybe it's possible to have one command that will delete and select another dataframe according to the rules above?

Comment: Sorry but the logic is unclear, if you have a X you want to keep it as main, else any row? The rest goes to the other DataFrame? Can you provide the output for the two DataFrame to be explicit?

Comment: I have duplicates in the `Car` column, I want them to be removed (and moved to another dataframe at the same time) those duplicates that do not have X in `cond`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the desired logic, you can use [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) to select the first X per group if any (else the first row of the group), to keep in the main DataFrame. The rest goes in the other DataFrame (`df2`).

```
# get indices of the row with X is any, else of the first one per group
keep = df['Cond'].eq('X').groupby(df['Car']).idxmax()

# drop selected rows
df2 = df.drop(keep)
# keep selected rows
df = df.loc[keep]
```

Output:

```
# updated df1
     Car  Year  Speed Cond
 0    BMW  2001    150    X
 2   Audi  1997    200    X
 5   Fiat  2020    180  NaN
 6  Mazda  2022    183  NaN

# df2
     Car  Year  Speed Cond
 1   BMW  2000    150  NaN
 3  Audi  2000    200  NaN
 4  Audi  2012    200  NaN
```

Comment: this is what i expected, can you explain what happened here?

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear, please read the comments and let me know any specific question

Comment: the result is good, I want to move the duplicates to a separate dataframe, I'd like to leave only those that have `cond == X`.  Will your code work if we have exactly two same rows? also move one of them to another df? I need in df_1 just one row with key, what if i have two rows Audi and condition X

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and if something doesn't work as you want, provide an updated example that demonstrates what fails and how you would like to handle it